# How could I prevent my product list to rerender while parent component updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-state

I have a **Main.js** component, that route to various components, including **Listing.js**.

- Main: it contains as state an array of the products added to the cart.
- List: it's a listing of the products. It contains as state all the products from database.

**My problem:** when I add a product to the cart by clicking on a button in List component, it adds the product to the cart, updating the state *cart* of **Main** component. Doing so, the **List** component rerenders, and I loose all the filters the visitor seted on the listing.

I'd like to prevent List from rerender when cart state of its parent component changes. Do you have any idea of how to do that ?

**Main.js** (parent component)

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, withRouter, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {List} from "./Listing/List";

class Main extends React.Component
{
    state={
        cart:[],
    };

    removeFromCart = product => //REMOVES PRODUCT FROM CART
    {
        let cart = this.state.cart;
        cart.map(item => {
            if(item._id === product._id)
            {
                item.count--;
                return item;
            }
        });
        cart = cart.filter(item => item.count > 0);
        this.setState({cart:cart}, () => {sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));});
    };

    addToCart = product => //ADD PRODUCT TO CART
    {
        let cart = this.state.cart;
        let productExists = this.state.cart.map(item => {return item._id === product._id}).includes(true);

        if(productExists)
        {
            cart = cart.map(item => {
                if(item._id === product._id)
                {
                    item.count++;
                    return item;
                }
                else
                {
                    return item;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            product.count = 1;
            cart.push(product);
        }

        this.setState({cart: cart}, () => {sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));});
    };

    componentWillMount()
    {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) this.setState({cart:JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'))});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='main'>
                <Header cart={this.state.cart} />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/listing' component={() => <List addToCart={this.addToCart} />} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

**List.js**, listing of product:

```js
import React from "react";
import {Product} from "./Product";
import Data from '../../Utils/Data';
import {Search} from "./Search/Search";

export class List extends React.Component
{

    state = {
        serie: '',
        products: [],
        filteredProducts: [],
    };

    addToCart = this.props.addToCart;

    obtainProducts = (request = {}) => //searches for products in database
    {
        Data.products.obtain(request).then(products => {
            this.setState({products:products, filteredProducts: products});
        });
    };

    displayProducts = () => {
        //Only products that has title
        const products = this.state.filteredProducts.filter(product => {return product.title;});

        //Returns REACT COMPONENT
        return products.map(product => {
            return <Product
                key={product._id}
                product={product}
                addToCart={this.addToCart}
            />
        });
    };

    searchHandler = (collection, types) =>
    {

        let filteredProducts = this.state.products;
        if(collection.length)
            filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => {return collection.includes(product.series);});
        if(types.length)
            filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => {return types.includes(product.type);});

        this.setState({filteredProducts: filteredProducts});
    };

    componentWillMount()
    {
        //init products collection
        this.obtainProducts();
    }

    render()
    {
        const productComponents = this.displayProducts();
        console.log('test');
        return(
            <section className='listing'>
                <Search searchHandler={this.searchHandler} />
                <div className='listing-content grid-4 has-gutter'>
                    {productComponents}
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

move 
    filter.State
from filter component to main component or use cookies

Comment: Is there any way to keep the filters related states to List component ? It seems more logical for me that this state is attached to List. Am I wrong ? (I'm juste starting with react ;))

Answer (score 1):

You can use componentDidMount method instead componentWillMount:

```
componentDidMount()
{
    //init products collection
    this.obtainProducts();
}
```

Comment: How does it help to avoid rerendering ?

Comment: componentDidMount() executive one time only, so ultimately obtainProducts also call only one time.

Comment: When I do this, I always loose my filters when the component rerender :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentShouldUpdate() to prevent this.

Comment: I tried, but I cand find a way to do that, I think I have a logical problem. Because if a prevent the List component to update, it won't rerender when filtering is made by visitor.